# How to remove kivy loading section?

Tags: android, python, kivy

When running a kivy app, it shows kivy icon and string "loading".

If its possible, I wanna remove it or change the icon.

Can you tell me how to remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I copied this answer from the kivy mailing list (original post [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/kivy-users/kivy$20loading$20screen/kivy-users/m8qPe_j0ZGQ/9PQ9kBsJUb4J) by Bill Jansen).

Just create an image, and put it in your buildozer.spec file, like this:

```
# (str) Presplash of the application
presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/images/goodstuff-android-presplash-256x320.png
```

Put any text you want there (like "Loading...") in the image.

Bill